# flutter center text inside button

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot work out why this text is not centering inside the button:

```
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        FavourDown();
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black, // background color
                        elevation: 5,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // button's shape
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        '-',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Result:

[image: button]

EDIT:

FULL ANSWER:

```
                  Material(
                    elevation: 20,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        FavourUp();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '+',
                            style:TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Try remove SizedBox

Comment: If you want make button to circle, just try `shape: const CircleBorder()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   If I remove sizedbox then I cannot customise the size of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elevated button is a fixed component, you can't customise it to your own sizes. (You could just set padding to EdgeInsets.zero in style of elevated button)

Better to use a Container and decoration to make your own button and Use the Centre() widget to centre the text in the container of your preference.

Here is an example :

```dart
      InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            // Logic
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 20, // any size you want
            width: 100,// any size you want
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Hello, World!'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Hope this helped

Comment: You got a quick example there mate?

Comment: I've added an example to the answer

Comment: Awesome mate, thank you.  Adding the full answer using your suggestion to the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to center text.
According to your code

```
                SizedBox(
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    FavourDown();
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black, // background color
                        elevation: 5,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // button's shape
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        '-',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```